# Proving the set $\mathcal H$ of Möbius transformations is a group under composition and finding a transformation that satisfies certain conditions

Tags: complex-analysis

1) Let $\mathcal H$ be the set of all transformations $T: \overline{\mathbb C} \to \overline{\mathbb C}$ of the form $T(z)=\dfrac{az+b}{cz+d}$ with $ad-bc \neq 0$ form a group under the operation composition.

2) Find the homographic transformation that sends the points $0,i,-i$ to $0,1,\infty$.

The attempt at a solution:

For 1), I have to prove i) associativity, ii)closure iii)existence of identity element iv)existence of inverse element.

Since composition of functions is associative and the transformation $T(z)=z$ is a homographic transformation, then i) and iii) are satisfied.

Regarding iv), I know that one can associate a transformation $T(z)=\dfrac{az+b}{cz+d}$ with a matrix $M=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ so I thought of considering the transformation $T'$ associated with the matrix $M^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{detM}\begin{pmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{pmatrix}$. I could prove that $T \circ T'(z)=z=T' \circ T (z)$

I had problems with ii)

Let $T(z)=\dfrac{az+b}{cz+d}$ and $T'(z)=\dfrac{a'z+b'}{c'z+d'}$ with $ad-bc, a'd'-b'c' \neq 0$. I want to show that $T'\circ T \in \mathcal H$.

$T' \circ T (z)= T'(\dfrac{az+b}{cz+d})=\dfrac{a'(\dfrac{az+b}{cz+d})+b'}{c'(\dfrac{az+b}{cz+d})+d'}=\dfrac{a'az+a'b+b'cz+b'd}{c'az+c'b+d'cz+d'd}=\dfrac{(a'a+b'c)z+a'b+b'd}{(c'a+d'c)z+c'b+d'd}$.

I've tried to prove that $(a'a+b'c)(c'b+d'd)-(a'b+b'd)(c'a+d'c) \neq 0$ but I couldn't, I think this is an algebraic nightmare.

Now, for 2), if the exercise asked to find $T$ which sends $z_1,z_2,z_3$ to $w_1,w_2,w_3$ with none of this points being infinity, then I think I wouldn't have any problems to find the required transformation.

In this problem, I could get conditions on the coefficients $a,b,c,d$ by the equations

$T(0)=0$ ($b=0$), $T(i)=1$ ($a=c-id$),

but how can I use the fact that $T(-i)=\infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you already know that $T$s can be associated with matrices - observe that composition of transformations is nothing else but composition of matrices. This observation solves 1) more or less immediately.

To make $T(-i)=\infty$, ensure that the denomimnator becomes $0$ for $z=-i$

Answer (score 2):

$T' \circ T (z)= \dfrac{(a'a+b'c)z+a'b+b'd}{(c'a+d'c)z+c'b+d'd}$ is in $PGL_2(q)$ so if we get $$(aa'+b'c)(c'b+dd')-(a'b+b'd)(c'b+d'd)\\=(aa'c'b+aa'dd')+(b'bcc'+b'cdd')-(a'b^2c'+a'bdd')-(b'bcd+b'd^2d')\\=...=(ad-bc)(a'd'-b'c')\neq0$$ because two latter multiplied terms are not zero.

Comment: Nice answer! +1

Comment: Sorry for the late question,but how did you get  $(aa'+b'c)(c'b+dd')-(a'b+b'd)(c'b)(d'd)$?  I thought it would be  $(aa'+b'c)(c'b+dd')-(a'b+b'd)(c'a)(d'c)$, since it is the determinant right?